# How do i specify a style for a single exposed filter?

Tags: 7, views

I have a View where i show some exposed filters; i would like to apply a particular CSS class only to a specific exposed filter.
I have seen that if i copy the views-exposed-form.tpl.php inside my theme directory and call it views-exposed-form--MYFORMNAME.tpl.php i can control the html code; i don't think it s a good thing to put code with

```
 if($widget->id==MYID) {}
```

inside the template ... which is the correct way to assign a style to an exposed filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you need the template for other reasons, but you can style it directly with CSS, using the ID.  See screenshot.  I happen to be using Better Exposed Filters module, which provides some nice extras controls.

[image]