# Custom rendering exposed filters in Views

Tags: views

I'm sorry if this is dumb question, but I'm creating a search page for a content type using Views in Drupal 7.   I am developing multiple exposed filters to achieve this, however, when the filters are rendered, they are done so side by side.  I would like them to stack on top of each other with the "Search" button at the bottom.

Is there something obviously simple I am missing or does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: you can achieve it through css

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795180/how-to-theme-exposed-filter-items-in-views-drupal-6

Comment: Worth checking this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41346/how-do-i-specify-a-style-for-a-single-exposed-filter

Answer (score 1):

Copy the views-exposed-form.tpl.php which is located at `<drupalroot>/sites/all/modules/views/theme` to your own theme folder. And it should be easier for you to style it. [Here is a tutorial you can follow](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2011/07/25/drupal-theme-the-exposed-filter-in-views/)

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I'll try a couple of these tutorials and let you know how it works out.